# A great joy or great joy

Tags: grammar

Just wondering which one is right

> It gives us a great joy.

or

> It gives us great joy.

Cheers
George

Comment: "It gives us great joy..."  But also "It is a great joy ..."

Comment: Could you please tell me, grammatically, why is it "it gives us great.."  the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of your sentence, ***joy*** is a *mass noun*, that is, something that cannot be counted.  (Other such nouns are water, air, fear, hunger, etc.)  So the correct sentence would be:

> It gives us great joy.

Note, however, as @GEdgar mentioned, ***joy*** can also be a *countable noun* in the sense of a specific thing that causes one to feel joy:

> It is a great joy.

The first two definitions given by the Oxford Living Dictionaries explain this:

> ***[joy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/joy)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. A feeling of great pleasure and happiness.
>
>    *‘tears of joy’*
>    *‘the joy of being alive’*
>
>    1.1 *[count noun]* A thing that causes joy.
>
>    *‘the joys of country living’*

Definition 1 is the one you're using; Definition 1.1 is the one GEdgar mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help. Roger Sinasohn.

Comment: @George - Glad I could help.  If you liked my answer, please consider upvoting it and, if it addresses your question fully, you could _accept_ it as the answer you were looking for (by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.)  You can get more info on this by taking the quick [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and there's all kinds of good info in the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).